# How do I remove infinite inertia in a CharacterBody2D? - Godot 4

Tags: game-development, godot, godot4

In Godot 3, there was a property in the move_and_slide (for Kinematic Body 2D) function called "infinite_inertia". I have a character body (2D) interacting with rigid bodies (2D), and the character body has infinite inertia, causing wacky interactions between the bodies.

Is there a way I can turn infinite inertia off for CharacterBody2D in Godot 4?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `infinite_inertia` has been removed in version 4
as per [this comment](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/31981#issuecomment-948801168):

> In 4.0, infinite_inertia is not needed anymore because one-way
> collision layer checks are supported now

Comment: How would I use one way collision layer checks in physics objects? I already have the RigidBody2D masked to the player's hitbox, the problems is the object gets smashed into the walls when the player pushes it into said walls. I want the player to move the objects, and not have the object interfere with the players movement